# Principled BSDF shader missing in node editor (2.79a)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

[image]everytime i open my saved project the Principled BSDF shader disappear from the list in node editor.

But in new tab it appear in node editor. i don`t know what to do (is that a bug)

Comment: Please, add screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 2.78 version, you launch old version, that doesnt support principal BSDF shader:

[image]

Comment: thaks bro i found the solution. its happning because i forget to reset the *.blend files default 2.79